# Finding employees from the smallest department

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I find a list of employee names from the department with the fewest employees?

The table structure of employee is:

```
| eid | ename | department |
```

Comment: just for clarity, you want to get emp names from departments where the emp count is the lowest of all departments? How is your data structured? You need a little more detail in your question

Comment: What do you mean 'lowest' employee?

Comment: @McAdam331 I think he means with the lowest number of employees, although he has yet to comment on this

Comment: @jbailie1991 that would make sense. Avi, this question is very broad and unclear. Try not to make your title and question the exact same. In addition, update your question to show your table structure and some sample data so other users can recreate it. In addition, it would be helpful to show what you have tried so far so you can understand why it didn't work.

Comment: lowest means least number of employees.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the department with the fewest number of employees, just select rows from your employees table and group by department to get the number of rows for each. You can sort by the count in ascending order and limit to 1 row to effectively get the minimum:

```
SELECT department, COUNT(*) AS numEmployees
FROM employees
GROUP BY department
ORDER BY numEmployees ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Then, to get the name of all the employees in that department, just select the name and use that subquery as a condition:

```
SELECT ename
FROM employees
WHERE department = (
   SELECT department
   FROM employees
   GROUP BY department
   ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC
   LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to count employees , but I was not sure how to use sub query for finding their names.

Comment: Not a problem. If this is the solution you use, accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it so future readers will know which answer solved your problem.